# Javascript: Display last time logged in

Tags: javascript, authentication, user-profile

Could the collective minds here point me to a JavaScript example
where the last time a user has logged in is displayed in their profile?

Update: I should point out that I'm using Node.js, server-side JavaScript.
Sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: and exactly how will JS be able to figure this out?

Comment: This is a job for server-side code. Not JS alone.

Comment: This is server-side, but you could maybe do some cookie magic to accomplish it, tho it is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
setCookie = function(name, value) {
   if(document.cookie.length > 0)
        document.cookie += "; ";
   document.cookie += name + ":" + value;
}

getCookie = function(name) {
   var cookies = document.cookie.split(";")
   for(var i in cookies)
       if(name === cookies[i].split(":")[0])
            return cookies[i].split(":")[1];
   return "";
}    

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".lastLogin").html(getCookie("lastLogin"));
  setCookie("lastLogin",new Date());
});
```